disable shrink of grid elements
I'm doing a pet project and I get a problem. I need two div's in the grid to have the same height on mobile devices and i want to add scroll when they overflow. But now the upper one squeezes the lower one. How can I fix this? I use Tailwind but i think its doesnt matter. Thanks!
I am attaching an image as well as a working prototype with github and codesandbox.
GitHub Link
Sandbox


You could consider:

Applying two explicit grid row tracks that are 50% of the element height using grid-template-rows.
Setting min-height: 0 to the parents of the grid that are in vertical flex layouts. This lets them shrink below their min-content heights.
Setting overflow: auto or overflow-y: auto to the text containers so that they are scrollable.



tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        dark: "#333",
        light: "#FFFAFA",
        primary: {
          100: "#B1D9F2",
          200: "#88B5A2",
          300: "#418393",
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        main: ['"Mulish", sans-serif'],
      },
    },
  },
};
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@0,200..1000;1,200..1000&display=swap');
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div class="font-main bg-primary-300 text-dark w-screen h-screen flex justify-center items-center">
    <div class="w-11/12 h-5/6 bg-primary-100 shadow-lg p-4 rounded-3xl overflow-hidden flex flex-col gap-8 lg:w-4/5 lg:h-4/5 lg:p-6">
      <header class="flex">
        <h1 class="text-lg inline-block uppercase font-bold content-end lg:text-2xl">sinoptik-app</h1>
        <img class="w-12 lg:w-16" src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='800' height='800' class='icon' viewBox='0 0 1024 1024'%3E%3Cpath fill='%23F4CE26' d='M492.2 451.6a129.5 129.5 0 1 0 259 0 129.5 129.5 0 1 0-259 0Z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23333' d='M621.7 607.4c-85.9 0-155.8-69.9-155.8-155.8s69.9-155.8 155.8-155.8 155.8 69.9 155.8 155.8-69.9 155.8-155.8 155.8zm0-258.9a103.2 103.2 0 0 0 0 206.2 103.2 103.2 0 0 0 0-206.2zM502.1 198a24.7 24.7 0 0 1 33.7 9l24.7 42.7a24.7 24.7 0 0 1-42.7 24.7l-24.7-42.7a24.6 24.6 0 0 1 9-33.7zm305.7 208.4c3.5 13.2 17 21 30.2 17.4l47.6-12.8c13.2-3.5 21-17 17.4-30.2-3.5-13.2-17-21-30.2-17.4l-47.6 12.8a24.7 24.7 0 0 0-17.4 30.2zm-13.2 110.9a24.7 24.7 0 0 0 17.4 30.2l47.6 12.8a24.7 24.7 0 0 0 12.8-47.6l-47.6-12.8a24.8 24.8 0 0 0-30.2 17.4zM665.7 161.8c13.6 0 24.7 11 24.7 24.7v49.3a24.7 24.7 0 1 1-49.4 0v-49.3c0-13.6 11-24.7 24.7-24.7zm167.1 69.5a24.7 24.7 0 0 0-34.9 0L763 266.2a24.7 24.7 0 0 0 0 34.9 24.7 24.7 0 0 0 34.9 0l34.9-34.9a24.6 24.6 0 0 0 0-34.9z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23FFF' d='m264.5 740.8-6.5.5c-60.5 3.4-111-49.7-111-111A111 111 0 0 1 270.5 520l-.1-6.9A154.1 154.1 0 0 1 575.9 484 129.5 129.5 0 1 1 597 741.2c-3.5-.1-6.9-.3-10.3-.7l-3.4.1H264.5z'/%3E%3Cpath fill='%23333' d='M252.4 767.8a127 127 0 0 1-87.9-35.8 140.7 140.7 0 0 1-43.9-101.7c0-71.3 54.7-130.2 124.3-136.7a180.8 180.8 0 0 1 179.4-160.9c78.4 0 147 50.6 171.2 123.3h1.4a156 156 0 0 1 84.4 286.9 148.8 148.8 0 0 1-95.1 24.1l-3 .1H265.8l-6.3.5-7.1.2zm5.5-222.1c-46.6 0-84.6 38-84.6 84.6 0 23.8 10 46.9 27.4 63.4a74.1 74.1 0 0 0 55.7 21.2l5.2-.4 2.8-.2h324.9l8.4.6c23.2.8 42.8-8.5 54.9-16.4 29.8-19 47.5-51.4 47.5-86.7a103.3 103.3 0 0 0-120-101.7l-25.4 4.2-4.8-25.3a127.8 127.8 0 0 0-253.2 29.9l1.4 30.9-30.7-3.5c-3.1-.4-6.2-.6-9.5-.6z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E" alt="logo"></header>
      <main class="grow flex flex-col gap-8 min-h-0">
        <div class="p-4 bg-light rounded-lg">
          <div class="flex flex-col gap-4 lg:flex-row lg:items-center lg:justify-between lg:gap-0"><input class="text-lg h-full border-solid border-2 border-dark rounded-md p-4 outline-none box-border md:text-lg lg:w-2/5 lg:text-2xl" name="search" type="text" value=""><button class="shadow-md p-4 rounded-lg transition-colors duration-300 text-md bg-primary-200 hover:text-light lg:text-lg">get weather information</button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="p-4 bg-light rounded-lg text-xl grow grid grid-cols-1 lg:texl-xl lg:grid-cols-2 max-lg:grid-rows-[repeat(2,50%)] min-h-0">
          <div class="border-b-2 border-dark pb-2 lg:pb-0 lg:pr-4 lg:border-b-0 lg:border-r-2 overflow-auto">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi similique quas dolore nesciunt sint blanditiis odit praesentium, commodi facilis ducimus repellat assumenda numquam expedita quaerat?</p>
          </div>
          <div class="pt-2 border-t-2 border-transparent lg:pt-0 lg:pl-4 lg:border-t-0 lg:border-l-2 overflow-auto">info</div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>





.root {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper {
  background: green;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.main {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(0, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50%);
}

.div1,
.div2 {
  overflow: auto;
}
<div class="root">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="header">
        <p>header</p>
      </div>
      <div class="main">
        <div class="div1">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias
            maiores ex aut voluptates saepe ea excepturi molestias magnam
            sapiente quasi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Alias maiores ex aut voluptates saepe ea
            excepturi molestias magnam sapiente quasi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit,
            amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias maiores ex aut
            voluptates saepe ea excepturi molestias magnam sapiente
            quasi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
            Alias maiores ex aut voluptates saepe ea excepturi molestias
            magnam sapiente quasi.Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur
            adipisicing elit. Alias maiores ex aut voluptates saepe ea
            excepturi molestias magnam sapiente quasi.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="div2"><p>item</p></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Thanks my friend, i think thats what i want!
